# getting uniques Ids from JSON logs

Tags: java, json, log4j

I am making my own Appender say MyAppender.
My log file contains different JSON Objects like

```
{
Id =""
------
-----
------
}
```

PatternLayout in my log4j.xml is like

```
<prop key ="log4j.appender.MYLOG.layout">org.apache.log4j.Patternlayout</prop>
<prop key ="log4j.appender.MYLOG.layout.ConversionPattern">"%m%n"</prop>
```

In append method

```
append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent){

 }
```

My main concerns are :

How LoggingEvent will deal with log files containing JSONObjects only log files are as {obj1}{obj2}{obj3}{obj4}. will it take individual objects or the whole log file at the same time.

As per my understanding LoggingEvent will take the whole log generated. so what I am trying is in my appender I have initially defined as `List<LoggingEvent> loggingEventList = new ArrayList();`

I have modified `append(LoggingEvent event)` as

```
append(LoggingEvent event){
loggingEventList.add(event);
}
```

So my concern is whether this will take the JSON objects as individual entry in List or not ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the jackson libraries

```
String s="{\"Id\": 200,\"Employee\": {\"Name\": \"ABC\"}}";
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode readTree = mapper.readTree(s);
System.out.println(readTree.get("Id"));

JsonNode jsonNode = readTree.get("Employee");
JsonParser parser=mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(jsonNode.toString());
Employee readValue = mapper.readValue(jsonNode, Employee.class);

System.out.println(readValue.getName());
```

You will require `jackson-core-asl` and `jackson-mapper-asl` libraries for this,be sure to use the latest ones.

I have just provided a example code snippet of how you can extract Node Object details from Json String,now what you need to do is,in your append method get the Json String from event and implement my code snippet to get the Id and other object that you want. try this if you get stuck ask again.

I can spoonfeed but I wont

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: I am new to log4j and JSON, I didn't get what you are trying to say can you please explain it ? I have edited the question.

Comment: As per my understanding LoggingEvent will take the whole log generated.

Comment: I have edited a bit please have a look. I edited the question itself because I was not able to comment whenever I comment it says some error

Comment: As my file contains multiple json objects {obj1}{obj2}{obj3} so if i will covert it to string , then How will I get Ids ??